# MariaDB SQL Error in Java only

Tags: java, sql-update, mariadb

I have an error in my Java application, Java version JDK 8u60, JRE 8u60, MariaDB java client 1.2.0

I am executing multiple updates in one call:

```
UPDATE `tblModbusData` SET 
     mintValue=952,
     datTimestamp='2015/10/14 12:01:35.223' 
WHERE mintAddress=302012;
UPDATE `tblModbusData` SET 
     mintValue=952,
     datTimestamp='2015/10/14 12:01:23.848' 
WHERE mintAddress=302010;
```

The error that is reported is below:

org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.mysql.MySQLProtocol getResult

```
WARNING: Could not execute query UPDATE `tblModbusData` 
SET mintValue=952,datTimestamp='2015/10/14 12:01:35.223' WHERE
mintAddress=302012;UPDATE `tblModbusData` SET 
mintValue=952,datTimestamp='2015/10/14 12:01:23.848' WHERE 
mintAddress=302010;: You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for 
the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE `tblModbusData` SET 
mintValue=952,datTimestamp='2015/10/14 12:01:23.848' ' at line 1
```

If I take the exact SQL and paste into HeidiSQL, there is no error and the updates are performed.

Comment: please try it without semicolon ; and show us the regarding java code

Comment: @SPlatten, could you log the sql expression in java code before send it to DB and then show this log here.

Comment: The error I posted was the exception thrown by the execute.  I have now resolved the issue by splitting the updates into seperate statements.